# how to prove using elementary comparisons that $x \log x \leq \log(2x^2-3x+2)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, logarithms

I am trying to show that $x \log x \leq \log(2x^2-3x+2)$ on $[1,2]$. The things is that these two functions are pretty close to each other:

[image]

so I have a hard time finding a simple function which trivially lies between the two.

Comment: Because the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function, this is equivalent to show $x^x\leq 2x^2-3x+2$ on $[1,2]$. Maybe this can help

Comment: Hint: derive twice LHS-RHS to get a rational expression; you should be able to prove a single root in the range $[1,2]$ by Sturm's test. From that, the first derivative has a single minimum and two roots (one at $1$). Finally the function itself has a $0$ maximum at $1$, a minimum in between and returns to $0$ at $2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did not think of Sturm's test, I was rather thinking of a comparison approach. Many thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: @Svetoslav Many thanks for the comment :-)

Comment: The numerator of the second derivative is $4x^4-4x^3+5x^2-11x+4$. It has two real roots, $0.4317\cdots$ and $1.2488\cdots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln(2x^2-3x+2)-x\ln x$. We want to show that $f(x)\ge 0$ on $[1,2]$.

We have
$$f'(x)=\frac{4x-3}{2x^2-3x+2}-(\ln x+1)$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{-4x^4+4x^3-5x^2+11x-4}{x (2x^2-3x+2)^2}$$
Here, let $g(x)=-4x^4+4x^3-5x^2+11x-4$. Then,
$$g'(x)=-16x^3+12x^2-10x+11,\quad g''(x)=-48\left(x-\frac 14\right)^2-7\lt 0$$
So, $g'(x)$ is decreasing. Since $g'(1)=-3\lt 0$, we know that $g'(x)\lt 0$ on $[1,2]$.

Hence, $g(x)$ is decreasing on $[1,2]$. Since $g(1)=2,g(2)=-34$, there exists only one real number $\alpha$ such that $g(\alpha)=0$ and $1\lt \alpha\lt 2$.

So, we know that $f'(x)$ is increasing on $[1,\alpha)$ and is decreasing on $(\alpha,2]$. It follows from $f'(1)=0,f'(2)=\frac 14-\ln 2\lt 0$ that there exists only one real number $\beta$ such that $f'(\beta)=0$ and $\alpha\lt \beta\lt 2$.

Hence, it follows from this that $f(x)$ is increasing on $(1,\beta)$ and is decreasing on $(\beta,2]$.

Since $f(1)=f(2)=0$, we know that $f(x)\ge 0$ on $[1,2]$.

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks :-) I went down this path too. I was originally after a function which lies between the two functions I wanted to compare ... I though am equally happy with your proof +1.

Comment: @Math-fun: We have $x\ln x\le px\ln x+(1-p)\ln(2x^2-3x+2)\le \ln(2x^2-3x+2)$ on $[1,2]$ for any $p$ such that $0\lt p\lt 1$. (though maybe you are not satisfied with this)

Comment: this is really nice too. But then we need to assume what we want to prove so that this holds. Many thanks :-)

Comment: @Math-fun: Assume? We've already proved it, so we can use it, can't we? Sorry, but I don't get what you want. You want to prove that $x\ln x\le \ln(2x^2-3x+2)$ on $[1,2]$, don't you? Also, you want to find a function $h(x)$ such that $x\ln x\le h(x)\le\ln (2x^2-3x+2)$ on $[1,2]$, don't you? I think I've answered these questions. Could you elaborate?

Comment: My concern was mainly on the approach to proving the inequality; namely by finding a function that is between the two. I agree that you proved the inequality and I agree that given the inequality you found a function that lies between the two. This is a nice proof.

Comment: @Math-fun: I understand. Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

We have to compare $(1+x)\log(1+x)$ and $\log(1+x+2x^2)$ on $I=[0,1]$.

That is the same as comparing:
$$ f(x)=(1+x)\log(1+x)-2x\log(2),\quad g(x)=\log(1+x+2x^2)-2x\log(2)\tag{1} $$
that are both vanishing functions on the endpoint of $I$. $f(x)$ is a convex function, hence $f(x)\leq 0$ on $I$. Since $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$ but $g$ is positive on $\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$, it is enough to prove $f(x)\leq g(x)$ on $J=\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. We have $f(x)\leq (1-2\log 2)x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ over such interval, hence it is enough to prove:
$$\forall x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right],\quad \log(1+x+2x^2)\geq x+\frac{x^2}{2}.\tag{2}$$
The last inequality is easy to prove if we notice that $\frac{\log(1+x+2x^2)}{x}$ is a concave function on $J$, or that $x+\frac{3x^2}{2}-\frac{5x^3}{3}$ is between the two terms given by $(2)$.

Comment: This is a nice proof. Many thanks :-) +1

Comment: @Math-fun: I am glad you like it, but I am still unsatisfied, the last step (any of the two) is quite involved, I feel there must be something more elementary. In which context this inequality arose?

Comment: I see, this is true. This came about in an exercise to bound an integral of the form $\int_1^2\frac{x^x-x}{(x-1)^2} dx$ by $2$. I could prove this equality by myself too but was obsessed by finding a simple approach.